# "Resource types cannot be changed" on serverless deploy

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

I was able to deploy to GCP Cloud Functions, then made some changes, now I can't deploy.

Clearly, my resource type was changed and it cannot be changed. But I didn't change it, and I don't know how to change it back.

Haven't been able to solve this error and there neither seems to be much documentation to look through nor any posts with the same issue. Anybody know what to do? Thanks in advance.

Error output:

```
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Compiling function "get_family_from_pub"...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Artifacts successfully uploaded...
Serverless: Updating deployment...
Serverless: Checking deployment update progress...

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: Deployment failed: TYPE_MISMATCH

       Resource types cannot be changed, previous (cloudfunctions.v1beta2.function) -> updated (gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions)
      at throwErrorIfDeploymentFails (/Users/jhschwartz/iag-patent-tool/node_modules/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/shared/monitorDeployment.js:71:11)
      at /Users/jhschwartz/iag-patent-tool/node_modules/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/shared/monitorDeployment.js:42:17
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              13.11.0
     Framework Version:         1.66.0
     Plugin Version:            3.5.0
     SDK Version:               2.3.0
     Components Version:        2.22.3
```

Comment: hey @jhschwartz , can you tell me how are you deploying your function? also can you update your Cloud SDK to the latest version "287.0.0" using `gcloud components update` then try to deploy again?

Answer (score 0):

According to their [change log](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), there was a [breaking change](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/pull/206) to serverless last week.  You'll likely need upgrade your cloud function. Instructions can be found in their [migration guide](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/blob/master/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md).

*Update*: You may also be able to cd into your function and run the following from your terminal

`sls remove`

`sls deploy`